# Installation error for tensorflow in EC2 instance of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2

I planned to deploy my AI app in aws EC2 instance as it has free trial , everything was going fine but when I was trying install tensor flow in that environment , I am getting below exception error .

Can any one help me on this ?

[image]

Comment: A question about Tensorflow installation should arguably be tagged as `tensorflow`, and not `artificial-intelligence` (edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> has free trial

The `t2.micro` which I assume you are using has only **1 GB** of ram. This is **not enough** to install `tensorflow` and you are probably getting a `MemoryError`.

I would suggest **upgrading** to `t2.small` with **2 GB** of ram. However, `t2.small` is **not covered by free-tier**.

Answer (score 0):

first you should set the environment variable then run the command

Comment: can you please elaborate